# Why do I get a NumberFormatException when I convert this

Tags: java

```
long converted = Long.valueOf(input);
```

input is a `String` object.

I want to convert the string value of a number into `long`.

I assumed To convert a string object, I need to use `.valueOf` to return a Long object.

Is it because I am storing the result in a primitive variable?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're getting this exception because the input is not a valid long.

Comment: What does input contain? What's the exact message of the exception?

Comment: try to print the string inside of input. and see if it is a valid number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a valid long as input it throws NumberFormatException. See below:

```
  long converted = Long.valueOf( "3" );
  System.out.println( converted );
```

Prints **3**

```
try{
    long converted = Long.valueOf( "TEST" );
    System.out.println( converted );
}
catch( NumberFormatException e ){
    System.out.println( "Your input is wrong.." );
}
```

This throws NumberFormatException, it's because not a valid number. And prints **"Your input is wrong.."**

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)):

`public static Long valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException`

Returns a Long object holding the value of the specified `String`. The argument is interpreted as representing a signed decimal `long`, exactly as if the argument were given to the `parseLong(java.lang.String)` method. The result is a `Long` object that represents the integer value specified by the string.
In other words, this method returns a `Long` object equal to the value of:

`new Long(Long.parseLong(s))`

Parameters:
`s` - the string to be parsed.

Returns:
a `Long` object holding the value represented by the string argument.

Throws:
`NumberFormatException` - If the string cannot be parsed as a `long`.